# Usage of the Custom functions inside of Excel (one-time purchase license)

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

Is it right, that there is no ability to use Custom Functions inside of Excel with a one-time purchase license? The custom functions are supported only in the Excel-online and Excel on Windows / Mac (connected to a Microsoft 365 subscription). Here is [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability), where I've found this information.
Also, do you know whether it is planned to add the support of custom functions to Office with one-time purchase license?

Answer (score 1):

yes this is correct. The Custom Functions feature was released after the 2019 One time purchase release, so that and features that it strongly depends on, like Excel Dynamic Arrays, will only be available currently via the next subscription, or perhaps the next one time purchase release of Office (TBD).

Comment: We've found in Commercial marketplace certification policies, that add-in for Office 365 must be fully functional with the supported operating systems, browsers, and devices for Office 2013, Office 2016, SharePoint 2013, and Office 365. Does it mean that we are not allowed to publish add-in that contains custom functions inside?

Comment: Hi there, this would depend. If the custom functions are critical to your addin running, them you can put a requirement set check into your manifest: “CustomFunctions” , MinVersion=“1.1”. This will cause the addin to only appear in builds that support custom functions (basically on an Office 365 subscription).  The other case would be doing the requirement set check at runtime and providing a proper experience on builds where your functions won’t be supported. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @KeyurPatel-MSFT, We're in the midst of trying to submit an add-in and have run into a problem with this. We require functionality from version 1.8 of the ExcelApi, but even after setting this in the Requirements section of the manifest, the partner center and testers seem to think that Excel for Mac 2016 is supported, even though it does not support versions of the ExcelApi beyond version 1.1.

Comment: Hi chucklay, let me get back to you on this Monday (sorry am out of office) with the store team. Excel Mac 2016 doesn’t support custom functions, so their may be some confusion on our side we need to clear up.

Comment: Hey there, we’ve investigated and this appears to be a known issue with our version strings. Internally, we will validate against the latest monthly channel version on Mac, but currently due to an issue the version in the validation report says “Excel 2016”.  For your particular case, custom functions are not supported in the one-time purchase versions of Excel or Excel 2016.  If you have any more issues with regards to submission, you can raise a support ticket here: https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport.  Or in your store submission, please indicate this stackoverflow listing.